# Django create choices based on database query

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm writing a Django 1.7 application that needs to create a list of choices for a form based on a query of partnered businesses stored in the database.  This list of businesses can change on the fly and the form choices need to auto-repopulate on the fly when needed.  I've created a Model named PartneredBusiness which stores all the needed business information.  I've also created a form:

```
class StartPartneredDeliveryForm(Form):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(StartPartneredDeliveryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['partnered_business'].choices = \
        [(business.id, business.contact.organization_name) \
        for business in PartneredBusiness.objects.all()]

destination_address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Destination'}))
partnered_business = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(), choices=())
```

This seems to work fine at first but if I add a new business into the database the list of PartneredBusinesses displayed by the form doesn't seems to update the list of choices until I restarted the server by stopping and re-running `python3 manage.py runserver`.

Can anyone give a clue as to what is up with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **instantiate your field** (not it's choices) in the constructor:

```
class StartPartneredDeliveryForm(Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StartPartneredDeliveryForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        choices = [(business.id, business.contact.organization_name) 
                   for business in PartneredBusiness.objects.all()]

        self.fields['partnered_business'] = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect(),
                                                              choices=choices)
```

Comment: @exquest hm, I don't see `form` used in the code provided. Are you sure you have the same code as in the answer?

Comment: yep.  got it to work just fine.  I copied the code wrong.  thanks.